# How do I link a table view cell to another specific table view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

What I'm trying to do is have a list of counties in a table view. When you click a county, another table view will show a list of resources you can select. I am using storyboards and Objective-C.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qL913.jpg) is my storyboard.

I don't want to nest the options into one table view because I think there are too many choices to be efficiently nested.
Here is my .h file for the county list table view:
    //  SecondViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,
UITableViewDataSource>
@end
```

My .m file for the county list table view:
    //  SecondViewController.m

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *tableData;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableData = @[@"Carter", @"Greene", @"Hancock", @"Hawkins", @"Johnson", @"Sullivan", @"Unicoi", @"Washington"];

}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[DetailViewController class]]) 
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSString *name = self.tableData[indexPath.row];
        [(CountyViewController *)segue.destinationViewController setName:name];

    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return self.tableData.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = self.tableData[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
@end
```

The County Resources .h file I want to display in table view format:
    //  CountyViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CountyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,
UITableViewDataSource>
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@end
```

The .m file:
    //  CountyViewController.m

```
#import "CountyViewController.h"
#import "CountyDetail.h"

@interface CountyViewController ()
@end

@implementation CountyViewController {
    NSArray *counties;
}

@synthesize tableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Initialize table data
    counties = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Resource1", @"Resource2", @"Resource3", @"Resource4", @"Resource5", @"Resource6", @"Resource7", @"Resource8", @"Resource9", nil];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [counties count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [counties objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showCountyInfo"]) 
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        CountyDetail *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.countyName = [counties objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
@end
```

Lastly, the detail of the resource clicked:
//  CountyDetail.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CountyDetail : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *countyLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *countyName;

@end
```

And the .m file:
//  CountyDetail.m

```
#import "CountyDetail.h"

@interface CountyDetail ()

@end

@implementation CountyDetail

@synthesize countyLabel;
@synthesize countyName;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) 
{
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Set the Label text with the selected county
    countyLabel.text = countyName;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

So my goal is to have the county selection go to another array of resources in another table view. I'm guessing I'm going to need a lot more arrays, but I just don't know the format or structure. I hope this is enough information, and if anyone can explain their answer, that would be extremely helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking on how to organize the data? If so, you can create a NSDictionary in your second view controller with a 'key' as county and the 'value' as an Array of resources attached to that county.

Comment: @realtimez i just want to know how to use objective c to create another table view but the data for the cells would change depending on which cell you clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

You can follow this delegate send the message to another tableView or others.

Comment: I can link to another table view but i want to change the data in it based on which cell i previously clicked

Comment: You can use Notification \ Delegate \ Block \ Property send the data method.